# Visually show the grouping of things based on relation

Tags: python, data-visualization, excel

I'd like to visually show how certain IoT device's functionality is linked together through some sort of heat map or bubble graph (whichever is appropriate). I have a list of 50 devices, and each device is categorized into 5 categories; Router, switch, WAP, Firewall, VPN.   If the particular device has a functionality, it will have a ONE in the columns that represent the functionality, and a ZERO in the columns that it doesn't.
ex:

```
Model          router        WAP        switch       VPN     Firewall
A              1             0          1            1       1
B              0             0          1            0       1
C              0             1          1            0       0
...
...
BX             1             1          1            0       1
```

My goal is to provide some sort of visualization that depicts the relationship between functionality. The best way I could visualize it myself is with a Venn diagram.

Is there a better/modern way to visualize it (preferably through excel or free software)?  I am new to this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the relationship between functionality"? Eg, do you want to see if certain functionalities tend to co-occur?

Answer (score 0):

A heat map would simply color in the 1's with a color of your choice and the zeros with the color of your choice. It wouldn't be a gradient. That will help visually, but it won't have that heat map effect.

A bubble graph generally works on 2 axis' and you have 5 points of data. While I'm not experience in making bubble graphs, I don't think you can easily or successfully plot 5 points on a 2 axis graph. You would most likely have a 5 Circles for each model number on the graph.

A Radar chart would not work because the data point is either a 1 or 0.
Stacked bar graph would be messy.

The Venn Diagram would work best in my opinion, however, Excel doesn't plot it automatically using the venn diagram smartart. You are going to need to put in quite a bit of work. I found a tutorial that may help you. He uses a 3 circle diagram, you would have to scale it up for 5, which adds complexity.

[Venn Diagram With Data Tutorial. Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oo0r800sNM)

[Venn Diagram With Data Tutorial. Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkRb7S6lXIg&ab_channel=IExcelAndSoCanYou)

Good luck!